# cucumber step definition not finding class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

i have a cucumber step definition that is not picking up on the object.

error is:

```
   | title       | description            |
      | First Issue | This is a first issue. |
      undefined method `issues' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/issue_steps.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Feature:

```
Background:    
    Given there is a release called "First Release"
    And that release has a feature:
      | title                | description   |
      | Make it shiny!       | Gradients! Starbursts! Oh my! |
    And that feature has a issue:
      | title                | description   |
      | First Issue          | This is a first issue. |
    And I am on the homepage
```

Routes:

```
resources :releases do 
      resources :features
 end

 resources :features do 
      resources :issues
 end
```

Step definition:

```
Given /^that feature has a issue:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    @feature.issues.create!(attributes)
  end
end
```

Step definition: feature

```
Given /^that release has a feature:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    @release.features.create!(attributes)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the step definition for `And that release has a feature:`

Comment: i've done that now, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you defining @feature?

The error message shows that the step is calling @feature.issues, but @feature is nil, which means that there's no way to get the issues.

Comment: do i need to define it in the factory files?

Comment: No, you just need to initialize it properly. Or: why do you expect @something to be anything different than nil, if you don't assign a value to it first?

Comment: You don't need to define it in a factory file (although that's a good place to do it, if you know how to use factory girl or something similar). It looks like you're expecting the release to automatically create its features and those features in turn to create their issues. That doesn't work - you need to create the feature (or use a factory).

Comment: So your saying i need to declare the @release object in my issue step definition? and not just feature and issue?

Comment: how do i define the @feature object dudes?